# How to correctly handle reconnects to a server in an app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm writing on an app which communicates a lot with a server.
When one minimizes the app, didEnterBackground is called I disconnect all connections.
When resuming the app I try to reconnect.
It's all fine if the server is available but I don't know how to handle if an error occurs (server down), as I cannot display anything within the AppDelegate.
Any suggestions how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NotificationCenter like that:

In your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"reconnectToServer"
 object:self];
}
```

In the didLoad-Method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reconnectToServer:)
                                             name:@"reconnectToServer"
                                           object:nil];
```

Add method that is called if your app is active again

```
- (void) reconnectToServer:(NSNotification *) notification{
  // Got to to a ViewController...
  ViewController *vc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
  [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to notify the user, you could consider using the NSNotificationCenter to publish failure messages and then you could respond to these from other locations?

Comment: I wanted to upvote this for the NSNotificationCenter hint, thx for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. `UIAlertView` can be created and shown from anywhere. The app delegate also has access to the app `window`(and thus the root view controller) so it could inject views.

Note that I'm not saying it's correct to have this functionality in the app delegate, because it isn't. You should have a network controller / monitor which handles this.

Comment: You're right too, but in my case the notification center thing is exactly what I want. I'll upvote once i have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

Many sorts of things may help you for check server validation.
If server down, you not receive any data in few seconds. This is may be error for user.
If server may down, you can use some sort of "ping" first. If ok, acquire a data, if not show server unreachable. 
If you use iOS API like *NSURLConnection*, *NSURLRequest*, *NSURLResponse* you can setup timeout for requests, perform sync request, and block/delegation requested data validation.